# Extracting background image from home page

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, href

I'm trying to extract the background image from this website. I can't find it in chrome dev tools when I right-click and view source. Not really sure where they are hiding the background image link. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the homepage: http://aframe.com/

Comment: `<img src="/themes/newTheme/images/default.jpg?v=1" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 1749.21713441654px; height: 1161px; max-height: none; max-width: none; z-index: -999999; left: -12.6085672082718px; top: 0px;">` And the URL is `http://aframe.com/themes/newTheme/images/default.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://aframe.com/themes/newTheme/images/default.jpg?v=1
heres the link my friend, it was in a div with the class "backstretch"

```
<div class="backstretch" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 1139px; width: 1903px; z-index: -999999; position: fixed;"><img src="/themes/newTheme/images/default.jpg?v=1" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 1903px; height: 1263.06960784314px; max-height: none; max-width: none; z-index: -999999; left: 0px; top: -62.0348039215687px;"></div>

<img src="/themes/newTheme/images/default.jpg?v=1" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 1903px; height: 1263.06960784314px; max-height: none; max-width: none; z-index: -999999; left: 0px; top: -62.0348039215687px;">
```

source: http://aframe.com/

Answer (score 2):

Images in devtools are found under the Resources tabs in Frames > Images (there might be a folder or two between that). Just be mindful that you're not illegally downloading copywrited images to use for your own project...